# Before pseudo element width equal to text of it's parent

Tags: css

I've got an issue, I'm working on a Wordpress and I want to initialize all `<h1>, <h2>, <p>, <ul>` etc... tags for my user.
That mean I can't change the HTML template, I can only use CSS.
What I want to do is :
[image: My <h2> tag]

What I currently have is this :

```css
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
h2:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #1c3b65;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg);
    tranform: skew(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<h2> Titre de niveau 2 </h2>
```

I know that I can put a width: fit-content to the  tag but the user won't be able to center, put text to the left or right with the Wordpress' WYSIWYG.
And if I put width: 100% to the before pseudo element it will take all the line, which is logic because the  tag is taking all the line to make to text-align CSS property effective.

What I want :

```css
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    width: fit-content;
}
h2:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #1c3b65;
    width: 110%;
    height: 120%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg);
    tranform: skew(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<h2> Titre de niveau 2 </h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `display: inline-block` on `h2` element and center it with `left: 50%` and `translate`.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #1c3b65;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<h2> Titre de niveau 2 </h2>
```

Comment: I could do that but as I said, if I put text-align: center in the <h2> tag, it will not be centered, it works in your example because you put the CSS property in the body. I want something easy for the user with Wordpress' WYSIWYG

Comment: Thanks but I think you didn't understand what I mean ! The thing is that the user will use Wordpress WYSIWYG, so when the user want his text to be centered, on left or on right of content, it will just do a <h2 style="text-align: center;">My content</h2>, I need <h2> width to be equal at 100% and meanwhile the before CSS pseudo element to be equal to the width of the text.

Comment: If you use `position: absolute` then width will be relative to first parent with `position: relative` not the text, but you could use `span` for example inside h2 element and make width of pseudo-element relative to that span. https://jsfiddle.net/3o2qgmhn/6/

Comment: I did insert a <span> tag inside my <h2> with JavaScript, thanks for helping me, I resolved it alone !

Comment: Glad I could help.